# Proving that for finite sets $m(A \cup B)=m(A)+m(b)-m(a \cap B)$; what is a good level of rigor?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I saw this exercise in Herstein's *Abstract Algebra*. I can do two proofs:

**Non-rigorous "proof" with words:**

To find $m(A \cup B)$, we can try adding $m(A)$ and $m(B)$. But any element which is in $A \cap B$ is counted twice, so we must subtract $m(A \cap B)$.

**Super boring and annoying proof**

Let the elements of $A$ be $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and let the elements of $B$ be $b_1, b_2, ..., b_k$.

Case $1$: $A \cap B = \phi$.

$\vdots$

Case 2: $A \cap B \not = \phi$. Then suppose $a_{i_1} = b_{i_1, a_{i_2}}=b_{i_2}$, ...

My question is, how can I construct a proof "in between"? The first one doesn't seem like a very good proof.

If there is no proof in between, how could I improve the first one? (The second is just too painful to do any version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you given that the *measure of a union* of *disjoint* sets is the *sum of the measures* of those sets?

Then your words are quite sufficient.   If needed then they can be expressed in algebraic terms:

$$\def\m{\mathsf m}\m(A\cup B) ~{= \m\big(A\cup(B\smallsetminus A)\big)\\=\m(A)+\m(B\smallsetminus A)\\= \m(A)+\m(B\smallsetminus A)+\m(A\cap B)-\m(A\cap B)\\= \m(A)+\m\big((B\smallsetminus A)\cup(A\cap B)\big)-\m(A\cap B)\\ = \m(A)+\m(B)-\m(A\cap B)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting $A \cup B$ into three disjoint subsets $A \setminus B$, $B  \setminus A$ and $A \cap B$. Then $m(A \cup B) = m(A \setminus B) + m(B \setminus A) + m(A \cap B)$, $m(A)=m(A \setminus B) + m(A \cap B)$, and $m(B) = m(B \setminus A) + m(A \cap B)$. The rest is just arithmetic. You aren't ever hand-waving the double counting, and the only combinatorial principle you use is the sum rule.

Answer (score 1):

$m(A \cup B)
=m(A)+m(B)-m(A \cap B)
$

Proof by induction
in the size of $B$.

Base case:
$m(B) = 0$.

Then 
$m(A \cup B) = m(A)$
and
$m(B) = m(A \cap B)
=0$,
so true.

Induction step.

Suppose true when
$m(B) \le n$.
If
$m(B) = n+1$,
choose a $b \in B$
and let
$B \smallsetminus b = B'$
so that
$B = B' \cup \{b\}
$
and
$m(B') = n$.

Then there are two possible cases:
$b \in A$ and $b \not\in A$.
For each of these cases,
evaluate the
left and right sides
of the equation
and show that they are equal.

Here's the left side.

For both cases,
$A\cup B
=A\cup B' \cup \{b\}
$.

If $b \not\in A$,
then
$A\cup B
=A\cup (B' \cup \{b\})
=(A\cup B')\cup \{b\}$
so
$m(A \cup B)
=m(A\cup B')+1$.

If $b \in A$,
then
$A\cup B
=A\cup (B' \cup \{b\}
=(A\cup \{b\})\cup B'
=A\cup B'$
so
$m(A \cup B)
=m(A\cup B')
$.

Now,
do the same
for the right side
for the two cases.

And I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

m(A) + m(B) = m(A $\cap$ B) + m(A $\cup$ B)

If U,V are measurable, then
m(U $\cup$ V) + m(U $\cap$ V)
= m(U $\cup$ V\U) + m(U $\cap$ V)
= m(U) + m(V - U) + m(U $\cap$ V)
= m(U) + m((V - U) $\cup$ (U $\cap$ V)
= m(U) + m(V)

Comment: That is what is being asked to be proven.

Comment: See edit.  @GrahamKemp