# If $A$ and $B$ have $n$ and $m$ elements respectively with $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Prove that $A\cup B$ has $m+n$ elements.

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ have $n$ and $m$ elements respectively with $A \cap B=\emptyset$. Prove that $A \cup B$ has $m+n$ elements.

The solution in the book starts by letting $f$ be a bijection from $\{$1,..m$\}$ onto $A$ and $g$ a bijection from $\{$1,..n$\}$ onto $B$
Then proving the function
$h:=$$f(i)$ if $i=1,...,m$
Or $g(i-m)$ if $i=m+1,...,m+n$ is a bijection from $\{$1,..,m,m+1,..,m+n$\}$ onto $A$$\cup$$B$

But I'm stuck with the surjection part

Comment: Do you mean $g(i)$ instead of $g(i-m)$? Either that or $g$ should be a bijection from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ onto $B$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin no it is $g(i-m)$ so that the entries become from 1 to n as $i=m+1,..m+n$

Comment: But $g$ is not defined for entries from $1$ to $n$. You have it defined on $\{m+1,\ldots,m+n\}$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin my fault, i will edit

Comment: If $x \in A\cup B$ then either $x \in A$ or $x\in B$.  If $x \in A$ then $h(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ and if $x \in B$ then $h(m + g^{-1}(x)) = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ has $m$ elements and $B$ has $n$ elements, there are bijections $f:\{1,\ldots,m\}\to A$ and $g:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to B$.
Now define $h:\{1,\ldots,m+n\}\to A\cup B$ by
$$
h(i) = \begin{cases}
f(i) & \text{if}\ i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}, \\
g(m-i) & \text{if}\ i\in\{m+1,\ldots,m+n\}.
\end{cases}
$$
First you should convince yourself that $h$ is well-defined.

To see that it is an injection, suppose $h(i)=h(j)$. Then either $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ or $i,j\in\{m+1,\ldots,m+n\}$ because $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $h$ maps $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ into $A$ and $\{m+1,\ldots,m+n\}$ into $B$. If $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then we have $f(i)=h(i)=h(j)=f(j)$, so the injectivity of $f$ gives $i=j$. Similarly we get $i=j$ if $i,j\in\{m+1,\ldots,m+n\}$.

For surjectivity, fix $x\in A\cup B$. Then either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. If $x\in A$, we can use the surjectivity of $f$ to obtain $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ such that $f(i)=x$. In this case $h(i)=f(i)=x$. On the other hand, if $x\in B$, then we can use the surjectivity of $g$ to obtain $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $g(i)=x$. Then $f(m+i)=g(i)=x$.

Comment: @user480659 To prove that a function is surjective, you fix an element in its codomain and show that it's mapped to by some element in the domain. Here the codomain of $h$ is $A\cup B$. Since an element in $A\cup B$ is in either $A$ or $B$, we can then use $f$ and $g$ normally.

Comment: @user480659 What do you mean by part of $x$ in the first and part of if in the second? The element $x$ is just an element of a set. It can't be broken into parts. What is nb?

Comment: i thought you meant $x$ to be a subset

Comment: @user480659 No, $x$ is just an element of the codomain $A\cup B$. To prove that $h$ is surjective, we need to show that for every $x\in A\cup B$, there is $i\in\{1,\ldots,m+n\}$ such that $h(i)=x$. If $x\in A$, then we will find our $i$ in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ using $f$. If $x\in B$, then we will find our $i$ in $\{m+1,\ldots,m+n\}$ using $g$.

Comment: i get it now. Thanks. Just forgot about that there is no intersection

Comment: @user480659 While the fact that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint is important in proving that $h$ is injective, we don't need it for surjectivity.

Comment: right. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Follows immediately from the result here

[Proving that for finite sets $m(A \cup B)=m(A)+m(b)-m(a \cap B)$; what is a good level of rigor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449789/proving-that-for-finite-sets-ma-cup-b-mamb-ma-cap-b-what-is-a-good)

that
$m(A \cup B)=m(A)+m(B)-m(A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Partition $A$ into $n$ one-element sets so that we have $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$, then partition $B$ into $m$ one-element sets so that we have $B=\bigcup_{i=1}^mB_i$. Then $A \bigcup B=(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i) \bigcup (\bigcup_{i=1}^mB_i)$.

If $A\bigcup B$ has more than $m+n$ elements then at least one one-element set has two or more elements, an obvious contradiction.

If $A\bigcup B$ has less than $m+n$ elements then at least one one-element set has no elements, again contradiction.

Your claim follows.

Comment: Of course, this works because all elements are different.

Comment: thanks, though i wish to understand the surjection part